# Why has one PC suddenly become unable to see one one particular website?

Tags: dns, ping, nslookup

The website is [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org).  I only noticed when a `push` timeout out.  The issue is only on one PC (Win10). Chrome, Firefox and Edge all have the issue. All other PCs' on the network, and an iPad, Android phones, have no issues with that or any other websites.  Here's the `ping` and `nslookup` output from the offending machine:

```
ping bitbucket.org -n 1 -w 10000 -l 1

Pinging bitbucket.org [104.192.143.3] with 1 bytes of data:
                       ^
                       --------------------------
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 104.192.143.3:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),

C:\PROJECTS\TOOLSRC>nslookup bitbucket.org
Server:  fritz.box
Address:  fd00::3a10:d5ff:fea7:80b2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    bitbucket.org
Addresses:  2406:da00:ff00::6b17:d1f5
          2406:da00:ff00::22c0:3470
          2406:da00:ff00::22c5:2ef4
          18.205.93.0
          18.205.93.1
          18.205.93.2
          ^
           --------------------------


C:\PROJECTS\TOOLSRC>tracert bitbucket.org

Tracing route to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.3]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     2 ms     3 ms  155.32.69.111.static.snap.net.nz [111.69.32.155]
  2     4 ms     2 ms     2 ms  155.32.69.111.static.snap.net.nz [111.69.32.155]
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4   130 ms   129 ms   128 ms  TWO-DEGREES.ear1.LosAngeles6.Level3.net [4.26.2.82]
  5   127 ms   129 ms   130 ms  7-1-10.ear1.LosAngeles6.Level3.net [4.26.2.81]
  6   134 ms   134 ms   134 ms  ae-0-11.bar2.SanFrancisco1.Level3.net [4.69.140.146]
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
....
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

and ipconfig output:

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fritz.box
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2406:e007:6457:7101:94ea:ae4d:deb0:63c2
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2406:e007:6457:7101:e845:1ef6:a791:c69d
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::94ea:ae4d:deb0:63c2%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.23
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::3a10:d5ff:fea7:80b2%10
                                       192.168.178.1
```

Now, I imagine the fact that ping is talking to a different IP address to what nslookup returns is possible significant.

What should my next step be?

Comment: I suggest opening an elevator cmd prompt and running 'ipconfig /flushdns' , then trying the ping again.  It may be that the specific server at 104.192.143.3 is down at this time.

Comment: I also get no pings back, so it may be that those hosts have ping-response turned off.  I note that the website is still up.  https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/  shows all operational.

Comment: tried the `/flushdns`.  Tried restarting PC and router.  I agree with you about the ping. The other PC's fail the ping test but they can open the web page.  But the offending machine gives `Pinging bitbucket.org [104.192.143.3] with 32 bytes of data:', but the others: `Pinging bitbucket.org [18.205.93.1] with 32 bytes of data:'.  The IP addresses should be the same, right?  Incidentally, I _can_ access the status page on the offending PC.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the website in incognito mode on the affected computer/browser, or have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: Neither had any effect.

Comment: Have you checked your HOSTS file and firewall?

Comment: <redface>  It was an entry in the hosts file!</redface>  I'm unsure when and why I added it, but it read: `104.192.143.3 bitbucket.org     # added to try to solve bitbucket push issues`  The IP address `104.192.143.3` does `whois` to `bitbucket.org` but `nslookup bitbucket.org` gives `18.205.93.1`.